# Unbiased estimator for the sum of numbers

Tags: statistics, parameter-estimation

Let $\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n \in \mathbb{R}$. We want to approximate the sum as follows
$$
S = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \alpha_i \approx \dfrac{n}{c} \sum_{i=1}^{c} \alpha_i,
$$
where $\alpha_i$ is picked with probability
$$
p_i = \dfrac{\alpha_i}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_i}.
$$
Some [lecture notes](http://cs.stanford.edu/people/mmahoney/f13-stat260-cs294/Lectures/lecture-2013-9-9-v1.pdf) I am reading say that this is an unbiased estimator, which seems reasonable but I am unble to prove. If I have understood correctly, I should show that the arithmetic mean of the estimator
$$
\dfrac{n}{c} \sum_{i=1}^{c} \alpha_i
$$
over all the possible choices of the $c$ indices, is $S$. I think I might use some kind of combinatorial trick, but I have no clue on a feasible way of enumerating all the possible combinations $c$ by $c$ of the $\alpha_i$'s, and any help would be much appreciated.

**EDIT:** I have added a few necessary details, as pointed out in some of the comments below.

Comment: Are  $\alpha_i$ iid ? If so, this follows directly from linearity of expectation

Comment: @leonbloy Thank you for pointing out this critical point. The lecture notes say that "probabilities are proportionate to the weight of the items", which I think means 
$$
p_i = \dfrac{\alpha_i}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_i}.
$$

Comment: It's unclear exactly what distribution of probability follow $(\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_n)$. If this is not iid, then this estimator may be a bad estimator

Comment: @gosbi I suggest you to consult your lecturer. An estimator is unbiased if ...

Comment: @gosbi: that doesn't make sense to me. A more elementary question: are $\alpha_i$ random variables? Or rather the random thing here is the "selected" set ?

Comment: @leonbloy I think your second option would make more sense considering the comment of gosbi. But a clarification is needed

Comment: @leonbloy Thanks, I edited the question and tried to clarify it. The $\alpha_i$ are just the numbers I want to to sum, they're not random variables. I want to select a few -- $c$ -- of them to estimate the value of the sum, and according to the lecture notes I am referring to, using the $p_i$ as above would reduce the variance of the estimator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation is rather bad, because it implies that we always sum the first $c$ numbers, not a random set. If I understand it right, we have

$$\hat S= \frac{n}{c} \sum_{j\in T} \alpha_j$$
where $T \subset \{1,2 \cdots n\}$, $|T|=c$, is a random subset. We could prescribe that the size $c$ is fixed, or that it is itself random.

We intend $\hat S$ to be an estimator of $S=\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i$

An alternative way of putting is using an indicator random tuple ${\bf X}$ with $x_i=1$ if $i\in T$ ($\alpha_i$ is selected), $0$ otherwise. Then

$$\hat S = \frac{n}{c} \sum_{i=1}^n {\bf x_i } \, \alpha_i$$
The estimator will be unbiased then iff
$$ E(\hat S)=\frac{n}{c} \sum_{i=1}^n p_i \, \alpha_i = \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i $$
where $p_i = E(x_i)$. This depends on how the set is selected - or the probability distribution of $X$ - we only have the restriction of $\sum p_i=c$.
(this is also wrong in the original question - these probabilities should not be normalized)

If we select subsets of size $c$ with uniform probability, then $E(x_i) = c/n$ and the above is true.
If instead the elements are selected with probabilities proportional to its values, we should have $p_i = \alpha_i \, c/S$ (this involves the quantity we want to estimate; difficult to say if this makes practical sense).

We could also try to compute (and perhaps minimize) the variance of the estimator, but I guess that this would be feasible only if we assume that the elements $x_i$ are independent (and hence $c$ is random).